# CodeIgniter: A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting this error when working with CodeIgniter:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'

SELECT `data` FROM `ci_sessions` WHERE `id` = '4j5h21j1us9nhah0qc1hqmmmevb1oa2f' AND `ip_address` = '::1'

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/life/app/delta/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

It's so frustrating. I've tried everything I know.

Here is the part of my controller i think the error is coming from

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE) {
        if ($this->session->userdata('usr_access_level') == 1) {
            redirect('users');
        } else {
            redirect('me');
        }
    }


        $data['login_fail'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->view('common/login_header');
        $this->load->view('admin/signin', $data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'usr_id' => $row->usr_id,
            'acc_id' => $row->acc_id,
            'user_name' => $row->user_name,
            'usr_access_level' => $row->usr_access_level,
            'logged_in' => TRUE
        );

        // Save data to session
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        if ($data['usr_access_level'] == 2) {
            redirect('me');
        } elseif ($data['usr_access_level'] == 1) {
            redirect('users');
        } else {
            redirect('me');
        }

}
```

Here is the Model for the controller

```
class _model extends CI_Model
```

{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function does_user_exist($email) {
    $this->db->where('user_name', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query;
}
```

}

Comment: do you have data column?

Comment: and also i don't see your select query in controller

Comment: Try this `$this->session->userdata('usr_access_level');`  instead of `$data['usr_access_level']`

Comment: And where do you get this `$row->usr_id` from I do not see the model for it

Comment: And which line here is 691?

Comment: @jyoti mishra there is no data column

Comment: I have just posted the model @wolfgang1983

Answer (score 0):

modify your code to below

```
if ($this->session->userdata('usr_access_level') == 2) {
            redirect('me');
        } elseif ($this->session->userdata('usr_access_level') == 1) {
            redirect('users');
        } else {
            redirect('me');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support. The problem was from my from my database, the columns 'data' and 'id' where not available in the session table. For anyone having the same problem go to the code-igniter user guide and check for the correct session table structure.